# does the url in the action attribute stop me from using my javascript code to redirect to another page after submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Ive been trying to ammend a third party form for some time now and no matter what i do im not getting the result. im very new to this and im wondering if not having control over the page that the action attribute points to could be stopping my progress. This is the code i have managed to put together to determine what url the form is redirected to following the form submission. It is based on the options selected by the user on the form.

E.g if they want to go to a workshop in birmingham or a workshop in london they will be sent to different pages.

For this to work do i need access to the url the action attribute is pointing to?
Is there anything else that may be wrong with the code?

if i point the action attribute to a function instead could that work or would it cause issues with the form?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function get_action() {
        var optn = document.getElementById("signup_User5");
        var optn_value= optn.value;
        var option = document.getElementById("signup_User8");
        var option_value= option.value;


        if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuklondonworkshop.html";
     } else if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukbirminghamworkshop.html";
     } else if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukmanchesterworkshop.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html"; 
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="London")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Manchester"))
           document.signupForm.action ="http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html"; 

} return true;
    }

</script>


<form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" target="_top" method="post"  action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" onsubmit="return checkMandatory(); "> 
<table><tbody>



<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User5" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser5" for="signup_User5">Please select the closest city to where you live from the list<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User5" id="signup_User5"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="London" >London</option><option value="Birmingham" >Birmingham</option><option value="Manchester" >Manchester</option></select>
</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User8" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser8" for="signup_User8">Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User8" id="signup_User8"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="Workshop Only" >Workshop Only</option><option value="Workshop + Audition" >Workshop + Audition</option><option value="Audition Only" >Audition Only</option></select>
</li>
</ul>



</li>
</ul>
<ul id="teamSelection"> 
<li class="formRow joinRow"><span id="confirmText"> </span>
</li> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="4" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="3" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="1" /> 
</ul> 
</td> 
</tr> </tbody>
</table> 
<div id="reqInfo">* required information
</div> 
<input id="formSubmit" type="submit" name="formSubmit"  style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;" value="Sign Me Up" onsubmit="return get_action();"/> 

</form>
```

Comment: I read your question and your description, but i couldn't get yet what are you trying to get as an answer.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy i dont have access to the coding on the page action is pointing to: action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739"

Comment: im wondering if this is stoping my form redirect javascript code from working

Comment: and if that isnt the case then im wondering if my code is wrong. The form is from a 3rd party software and i am trying to ammend it

Comment: Don't submit the form if you want your js code to continue executing. Use ajax (XMLHttpRequest) to post the values directly instead. Then when the result returns you can change window.location.href to anything you want

Comment: @slebetman please can you give me an example?

Comment: What normally happens when you submit the form to `http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739`?

Comment: @jasen i sends me to a Thank you page created by the third party company telling you to check your email to double opt in. I want to send them to different pages instead which are determined by what the person has chosen on the form